# UICollectionView scrollToItem does not work

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

My horizontal one line `UICollectionView` has a content inset and size set:

```
let space = collectionView.width

collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: space / 2, bottom: 0, right: space / 2)
collectionView.contentSize  = CGSize(width: CGFloat(items.count) * cellWidth, height: 45)
```

When a cell is tapped, I want to scroll it to the center of the scrollview. I hoped this would just work:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

However, this all this does is scrolling the left-most cell's left side to the center, no matter which cell is tapped.

What could I be doing wrong?